# How do i only show the first 1000 results on a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

```
> db.a.aggregate([{$lookup: { from: "werkstuecke",localField: "_id",foreignField: "AuftragsID", as: "test"}}]).pretty()
```

This Statement Shows every result but I only want the first 1000 records to be shown.
How can i manage to do this?

Comment: use [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please  use  [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html)   to  reduce the result  nums  .

you can use it    after  your "$lookup" .
 like this

```
db.a.aggregate([
{$lookup: { 
          from: "werkstuecke",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "AuftragsID", 
          as:"test"
}},
{$limit:1000}
]).pretty()
```

also  you can use it  in  front of your  `$lookup`  to  reduce  the document  to join  (speed up the operation ) .

```
db.a.aggregate([
{$limit:1000},
{$lookup: { 
          from: "werkstuecke",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "AuftragsID", 
          as:"test"
}},
// here  may has  other operation  like  $unwind
{$limit:1000}
]).pretty()
```